# Через фокус параболы у^2=10х проведена хорда, перпендикулярная к ее оси. Определить длину этой хорды

Tags: математика

Через фокус параболы `у2 = 10х` проведена хорда, перпендикулярная к ее оси. Определить длину этой хорды.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы за Вас решили Вашу задачу?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автор вопроса мог бы и учебник почитать...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читайте, что такое парабола.

Для параболы в каноническом виде [image: введите сюда описание изображения] фокус находится в точке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Значения *y* при [image: введите сюда описание изображения], само собой, равны [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Расстояние между этими точками, думаю, и сами найдете? :)